# Hook for single product thumbnail

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

Is there any hook to change the single product thumbnail? I did search a lot on SO as well as over the internet but no luck.

With 'thumbnail' I don't mean changing the size of the current image but I want to completely change/replace the product image (thumbnail) with a new image based on some scenario.

```
public function pn_change_product_image_link( $html, $post_id ){

    $url =  get_post_meta( $post_id );
    $alt = get_post_field( 'post_title', $post_id ) . ' ' .  __( 'thumbnail', 'txtdomain' );
    $attr = array( 'alt' => $alt );
    $attr = apply_filters( 'wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', $attr, NULL );
    $attr = array_map( 'esc_attr', $attr );
    $html = sprintf( '<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/38/WP_Suspension_logo.svg/2000px-WP_Suspension_logo.svg.png"', esc_url($url) );
    foreach ( $attr as $name => $value ) {
        $html .= " $name=" . '"' . $value . '"';
    }
    $html .= ' />';
    return $html;
}
```

This is what I'm doing now but it's throwing an error.

Filter, Hook:

```
post_thumbnail_html
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I believe is an updated version of one of the other answers' comments. This function replaces the width and height attributes, but OP wanted to change the src. I imagine the solution would be similar, except using preg_replace to replace the src instead.

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html','remove_single_product_image_attrs',10,2); 

function remove_single_product_image_attrs( $sprintf, $post_id ){ 
  return preg_replace( '/(width|height)="\d*"\s/', "", $sprintf ); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I hope this filter will help you.

```
apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html',  $sprintf,  $post_id );
```

Ref: http://hookr.io/filters/woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html/

Comment: That may well be the right one, but that's not very helpful documentation. e.g. what's `$sprint` here? I don't see `$sprint` in the apply_filters here in the latest woocommerce source. Could you e.g. link to the woocommerce docs for this instead? And it's not 100% clear what your fix is either: do you mean he should hook that filter intead of `post_thumbnail_html`?

Comment: add_action('woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html','remove_single_product_image_attrs',10,4);

function remove_single_product_image_attrs( $image_html, $attachment_id, $post, $image_class ){
    return preg_replace( '/(width|height)="\d*"\s/', "", $image_html );
}